# Removing Careers account

Tags: support

I had some accounts on Stack Exchange that I wasn't using. So I filled the contact forms to remove those accounts. Now I want to remove my Careers account too, since I'm not looking for a job, but there's no Contact Us link on Careers.

How can I remove my Careers account?

Comment: You're not looking for a job but you want to remove your Careers profile? I'm not looking around for work either but I still keep it around; I just don't let myself show up in any of the searches.  Deleting it seems like the nuclear option.

Comment: @Makoto The problem is I'm a hobbyist coder. I couldn't code a line if it was my job. I don't EVER plan to work as a coder.

Comment: There is no "contact us" but a "support" link: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/support I would be surprised if they outright reject non-employer mail.

Comment: While that raises more questions than it answers, I suppose that's fair.  I'd say email support about it and see what they can work out with you.

Comment: Thanks, I emailed them. It was my mistake to create the account in the first place.

Comment: I would point out that sometimes *non* programming careers show up in there too.  Project management, graphics design, tech support, sysadmin, manager, human computer interface, tech writer... these are things that one *may* be interested in even without the "I can't code" aspect.  Just because its primarily on Stack Overflow doesn't mean that all the job positions listed are programming.

Comment: @MichaelT Thanks. I know that, but I live in Turkey, where there's absolutely no exciting development jobs. I can't develop software if I'm not excited about the project. And what I develop is mostly open source stuff. I don't think anyone would pay me to develop not very popular open source stuff. Besides, I'm a writer, and I love my job.